# Dynamic Image Name to shorten code

Tags: c#

I got a very long code that I call to check tiles from a chessboard and displays a proper image to a picturebox with the same tile name.

```
    private void DisplayBoardDisplayTile(string xtile, string piece)
    {
    if (xtile == "a1")
        {
            if (piece == "0000") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0000; } //empty
            if (piece == "0001") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0001; } //white pawn
            if (piece == "0010") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0010; } //white rook
            if (piece == "0011") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0011; } //white knight
            if (piece == "0100") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0100; } //white bishop
            if (piece == "0101") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0101; } //white queen
            if (piece == "0110") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0110; } //white king
            if (piece == "0111") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0111; } //black pawn
            if (piece == "1000") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S1000; } //black rook
            if (piece == "1001") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S1001; } //black knight
            if (piece == "1010") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S1010; } //black bishop
            if (piece == "1011") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S1011; } //black queen
            if (piece == "1100") { a1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S1100; } //black king
        }
```

Complete code is at this link: https://pastebin.com/XLbEeZZH

If the tile is shaded, I use a image name starting with "S" if not "U".
It also checks for the piece in which the value of the piece is almost identical to the image name.

I want to shorten the code in such a way (if possible) make use of a Dictionary of Images named

```
tiles[xtile].Image = ?????."S"+piece;
```

or something similar.

Here is the sample of the [image names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRkBC.png) I used.

Comment: This looks like some kind of school project, to what extent can you change the structure of the code?

Comment: It's not a school project. Just keep the class variables intact (xtile & piece).

Comment: `tiles[xtile].Image = (Image) Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("S"+piece);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up some dictionaries to map from `xtile` and `piece` to get the code down to one line where you just go `_tiles[xtile].Image = _shadings[xtile][piece];`.

Try this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image> _shaded = new Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image>()
{
    { "0000", WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0000 },
    { "0001", WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S0001 },
    //etc
    { "1100", WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.S1101 },
};

private static Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image> _unshaded = new Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image>()
{
    { "0000", WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.U0000 },
    { "0001", WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.U0001 },
    // etc
    { "1100", WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.U1101 },
};

private static Dictionary<string, PictureBox> _tiles = new Dictionary<string, PictureBox>()
{
    { "a1", a1 },
    { "b1", b1 },
    // etc
    { "h8", h8 },
};

private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image>> _shadings = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image>>()
{
    { "a1", _shaded },
    { "b1", _unshaded },
    // etc
    { "h8", _shaded },
};

private void DisplayBoardDisplayTile(string xtile, string piece)
{
    _tiles[xtile].Image = _shadings[xtile][piece];
}
```

Comment: Uhm, shaded and unshaded tiles have noting to do with white and black pieces.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was trying to picture in my mind. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Everthings ok, except for the _tiles. On {"a1", a1} the a1 returns an error (field) Picturebox Form1.a1    A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.a1'

Comment: I removed the _tile completely and used (this.Controls[xtile] as PictureBox).Image = ... as @Slai suggested.

Comment: @EmanSantos - That's fine, just keep in mind that my solution has compile-time safety, but Slai's doesn't. This means that if you change the name of any of the controls the code will compile for Slai's but it will throw an error at run-time. My solution will let you know when you compile. That's why I prefer the way I do it.

Answer (score 4):

Resources can be retrieved by name:

```
Image img = (Bitmap)WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("S0000");
```

and the S or U can be calculated with few bit operators (not tested):

```
(this.Controls[xtile] as PictureBox).Image = (Bitmap)WindowsFormsApplication5
     .Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("SU"[xtile[0] + xtile[1] & 1] + piece);
```

Comment: I like this approach too, but I worry about this not being compile-time checked. It's good if you've got appropriate unit tests or good programming practices, but otherwise it can easily be broken. Excellent alternative though.